# RPM: find subpackages names from spec

Tags: package, rpm

How could I known what are the subpackages of a spec file?
There is any macro expanding to the list of package+subpackages?

I do not want to use grep because subpackages may be defined using -n or even be defined by another macro (which leads to re-eval it)

Example:

```
$ rpmbuild project.spec --eval '%packages_list'
```

Comment: I don't believe the rpm commands support this kind of query.

Answer (score 3):

I generally use the simple form:

```
rpm -q --specfile FILENAME.SPEC
```

Answer (score 2):

Little bit of python will do the job for you. I am sure rpm-4.8 also had python bindings with spec object (assume a file with +x set and name specinfo.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                                                                        
import sys
import rpm
spec = rpm.spec(sys.argv[1])
for subpackages in spec.packages:
    print subpackages.header["name"]
```

can be used to get all subpackages. You can run this command on spec file in same directory as:

```
python specinfo.py <spec file>
```

Answer (score 1):

rpm -q --queryformat="%{NAME}\n" --specfile project.spec

Answer (score 0):

Well, I used a bit of sed, but since I also used `rpmspec` to first unroll the macros this should be fairly OK:

```
$ export SPEC_FILE=maven-surefire.spec
$ rpmspec -P $SPEC_FILE | grep '^%package' | sed "s/-n //;t end;s/^/${SPEC_FILE/.spec}-/;:end;s/%package //"
```

Note that it would need `basename` call to work with paths, but otherwise should be quite error-resilient.

Comment: hmm, not feasible for me because my working environment hasn't rpmspec installed by default (maybe cause it's rpm-4.8.0-12.el6.x86_64?)